# Solving a scary looking cubic by hand

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations, roots, cubics

I came across this question in the [Resonance](https://www.ias.ac.in/Journals/Resonance_%E2%80%93_Journal_of_Science_Education/) Journal of science education (April edition 2021). Unfortunately it is only available in the hard copy of the magazine. There is a small poem cited from $The \ Ladies' \ Diary \ 1776$ that proposes the following problem,

[image: Find the ages of Marie and Cloe]

> $x^2+xy+y^2=1087$
>
> $x^4+x^3y^3+y^4=45777295$

I was able to find a cubic equation in xy by substituting the value of $x^4 + y^4$ from first equation into the second equation,

$(xy)^3-(xy)^2-2174(xy)-44595726=0$

Now the questions I have is,

1. Is this the correct way to approach such a problem? If not please provide an alternative approach.
2. How do I proceed from here? I prime factorised the last term into $44595726=2×3×7×17×62459$, now do I need to consider all possible combinations of products of these prime factors and plug it in the equation to solve it? (Assuming of course that there were no calculators nor polynomial equation solvers in 1776)

Comment: Not very sure, but assuming $x$ and $y$ being positive integers we can put some bounds on them, and probably solving a great part of the problem in the way.

Comment: The first equation is $(x+y)^2=1087-xy$, so you are looking for perfect squares less than 1087. This should restrict $x$ and $y$ quite a lot.

Comment: Try the substitution $m=x+y,\ n=x-y$. The first equation becomes $3m^2+n^2=4\times 1087.$ Perhaps the second equation also simplifies?

Comment: @Paul so that gives us $x+y≤32$ since $33^2=1089$ applying AM-GM will give us $xy≤256$ but the root of the cubic is 357.

Comment: The equation by @Paul is incorrect. The correct is $(x+y)^2=1087+xy.$

Comment: @md2perpe unfortunately it doesn't simplify as much as the first one :(

Comment: Or something like $(x-y)^2=1087-xy$ would be better, implying $x-y\leq 32$.

Comment: @ultralegend5385 but that relation is also incorrect

Comment: I think you mean $(x-y)^2=1087-3xy$ but since we can't apply AM-GM here it doesn't directly help us with the cubic

Comment: One-liner in Python:
```[(x,y) for x in range(100) for y in range(100) if x**2+x*y+y**2==1087 and x**4+x**3*y**3+y**4==45777295]```
Answer: `[(17, 21), (21, 17)]`

Comment: $(x-y)^2=1087-3xy$ and considering the text will restrict you to 7 possible values of $xy$, which can then be tested in the cubic. One of these is $xy=357=17\times 21$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The second equation you are given has a subtle hint.

If $x$ and $y$ are large, then the $x^3y^3$ which is degree 6 dominates the other terms.

We can establish this dominance more rigorously by observing that the first given equation forces $x,y\le32$. Then $x^4+y^4$ cannot exceed $2×32^4=2097152$, which is less than $5$% of the right side of the second equation, forcing the $x^3y^3$ term to make up all the rest.

So $xy$ should be close to the cube root of the right side of the second equation, this root being between $300$ and $400$.

The factor that fits this estimate and your product is $3×7×17=357$, so try that value for $xy$.

Assuming that $xy=357$ works (solving the cubic equation), the first equation then gives $x^2+y^2=730$. Then the larger factor must be at least $\sqrt{xy}=\sqrt{357}$ and less than $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\sqrt{730}$. The only factor of $357$ that falls within these limits is $21$, so the values of $x$ and $y$ would be (in either order) $21$ and $357/21=17$.

Comment: +1 on this answer. (If $x$ is very small, then the dominating term would be $y^4$,  but in this case $y\approx80$, and this is nonsense since $1087 >y^2 \approx 6700$.)

Answer (score 2):

From where you pointed out, I could reduce the candidates.

$x$ and $y$ are ages, so they are integers. $xy \mid 2\times3\times7\times17\times62459$; we can neglect the 62459 factor since people cannot live that long.

Product of two people's ages are divided by $2\times 3 \times 7\times 17$. By modular arithmetic, we can assert that $xy \mid 7$, $xy \mid 17$ and $xy \not\equiv 1 \pmod3$. (This is somewhat tedious to do by hand, but I think it is doable.) Now there are three candidates for $xy$; $2\times 7\times 17$, $3\times 7\times 17$ or $2\times 3\times 7\times 17$. Answer is $3\times 7 \times 17$, and their ages would be $17$ and $21$. (Technically $(7,51)$ or $(3,119)$ are also possible.)

(+Edit)
Up to here I was solving the cubic, but more informations were given; with $x^2 + xy + y^2 = 1087$, $(x+y)^2 = 1087 + 357 = 38^2$, so $0<x+y=38$ and $\{x, y\} = \{17, 21\}$ is easy.

Comment: The product divides into the expression you cite.

Comment: This answer is not right. Even wolfram alpha don't agree with you https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%2Bxy%2By%5E2%3D1087%2C+x%5E4%2Bx%5E3y%5E3%2By%5E4%3D45777295

Comment: Well, yes, I was just solving the cubic which yields $xy =3\cdot 7 \cdot 17$, and by using the given equation we are reduced to exact $x, y = 17, 21$.

Comment: @Jitendra Singh Okay, I edited.

Comment: Your edit is what is OP asking How did you know you had to 730 how did you get to know you have to produce 38^2 also inform the reverse state

Comment: @JitendraSingh OP asked if we have to examine all of the possible combinations, and my answer is about how to reduce the number of combinations into doable set of candidates. Kindly read my post again.

Comment: I am confused  how did you write xy|7 and xy|17 ? Did you mean 7|xy and 17|xy

Comment: @QuiGonnJinn This answer is solving the scary-looking cubic of $xy$, so there's nothing to do with individual $x$ and $y$.

Comment: In particular I'm not able to follow "By modular arithmetic, we can assert that xy∣7, xy∣17 and xy≢1(mod3)" how did you arrive here? I know basic modular arithmetic but I'm not able to understand your approach

Comment: @QuiGonnJinn $\pmod 7$ for example. $t^3 - t^2 -2174 t -44595726 \equiv t(t^2 - t +3) \pmod 7$. $f(t) = t^2-t+3$ has values $f(0), \dots, f(6) = 3, 3, 5, 9, 15, 23, 33$ so this does not vanishes mod 7. So we have $t \equiv 0\pmod 7$. The calculation is tedious but doable by hand.

Comment: "Now there are three candidates for xy; 2×7×17, 3×7×17 or 2×3×7×17". Not for me. Putting $xy$ even renders the cubic polynomial $\equiv2\bmod4$. We are left with the one correct (odd) value.

Answer (score 0):

In year $1776$, they knew how to solve  cubic equations (they were first studied in the $11^{\text{th}}$ century by Omar Khayyam in Persia).

So, they knew that the only real root of
$$(xy)^3-(xy)^2-2174(xy)-44595726=0$$ is $(xy)=357$.

Now, using the first equation, we have that
$$(x+y)^2=(x^2+xy+y^2)+xy=1087+357=1444=38^2$$
$$(x-y)^2=(x^2+xy+y^2)-3xy=1087-3\times 357=16=4^2$$